# miliseconds replace from 6 to 3 decimals with javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I need to replace 02:04.887004 to 02:04.887 with jquery or js.

Other times I have microseconds just with four decimals (02:04.8348) and I would have 02:04.834

I would use regexp to find $:[d][d].$ and then return it but with the three decimals

Comment: Perhaps use *indexOf* to get the position of the decimal point, then get the substring from 0 to that index + 3? Or you could find the length of the string after the decimal point and slice to -(that length - 3). Or…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the length of the string is reliable, you can just trim the unwanted characters from the string, e.g.

```js
let time = '02:04.887004';

// If format is reliable, get first 9 characters
console.log(time.substr(0,9));

// If length might vary and number of decimals is at least 3
// Trim from end
console.log(time.slice(0, -(time.length - time.indexOf('.') - 4)))
// Trim from start
console.log(time.substr(0, time.length - time.indexOf('.') + 2));
```

If the format is more unreliable, you have more work to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression or a split function or a substring on the string to format your timestring. Here is an example of the three:

```js
const time = '02:04.887004';
const regex = /[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}\.[\d]{3}/

const formatTime = time => {
  const match = time.match(regex);
  return match ? match[0] : match;
}

const formatTime2 = time => {
  const m = time.split(':').shift();
  const s = time.split(':').pop().split('.').shift();
  const ms = time.split('.').pop().substr(0,3);
  
  return m + ':' + s + '.' + ms;
}

const formatTime3 = time => {
 return time.substr(0,9);  
}

console.log(formatTime(time));
console.log(formatTime2(time));
console.log(formatTime3(time));
```